# Trigger for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am importing a csv file into a database table using 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'. The complete query for curiosity is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".addslashes($current_file)."' REPLACE INTO TABLE $current_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '" . '"' . "' ESCAPED BY " . "'\\\\'" . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ($toVars) SET $setCols
```

Now, what that is doing in a nutshell is loading csv rows into `table_A`. What I want to do is  create a memory table that will log every single row that is ever entered into `table_A`. I am going to achieve this using **MYSQL Triggers**. Now I am familiar with using Triggers with `inserts` that are performed. By my question is; how to make a `AFTER` trigger for a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command?

The trigger should fire only when the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query has completed everything. It shouldn't fire on each incremental insert or whatever the case may be.

Comment: There are no statement level triggers in mysql yet...

Comment: Just run your stetement after LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Comment: @DevartThat's not what I want to do. I want to setup triggers in my database that will facilitate data movement at the mysql level not the php level.

I was under the impression statements were supported as of MySQL in version 5.0.2? I can already use statments like WHERE and OR in triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a table that tracks these bulk uploads, like who ran them, how long they took, etc?

If so, you can use it as a sentinel and put the trigger there to do the bulk operations on the freshly loaded data in the other table.

Make sense?

Comment: I have my database abstracted into layers made up of tables that keep track of disposition, sources, methods of entry, etc etc. That's not a problem. But I don't understand that last part about using it as a sentinel?

Comment: When you update your meta data to say that the load is finished, fire a trigger then to update the freshly loaded data.  I meant sentinel in [this context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

Comment: hmm like a progress table? With a bool of true and false for any given task. So if php fires up and starts processing stuff, I could make the php code at the very end change the bool value on that table which will have a TRIGGER value to do something ON UPDATE WHERE foo.column = 'false'?

Comment: Come to think of it, I do have a table I call 'set' which keeps track of data instances to enter the system and encapsulates them in what I call a 'set'. So a import is a set, a manual entry is also a set. I could have a field in that set table for the bool trigger.

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together!